# Matching each char in strings

Tags: c#, string, matching

I am trying to match user input with the pattern "ran,om", where "ran om will match exact characters with order, and "," can match to any characters. The program will find words in the arrayList for example in ArrayList dictionary{rammm, random, ranom}, for example, random will match, but ranom will not.

I have written the following code, but it only finds any words contains any of the characters in the user input:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userinput.Length; i++)
{

        foreach (string line in dictionary)

            if (line[i] == userinput[i])
            {
                Matching.Add(line);
            }
        foreach (string line in FirstCom)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what do I do next? (p.s no regex will be using in this program)

Comment: This is the reason Regex exists - please use them OR show code you tried to write and detailed problem you have with that code if you need to implement regular expression engine (or light version of one) yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    public static bool IsMatch(string pattern, string line)
    {
        var patternSplit = pattern.Split(',');
        if (!line.StartsWith(patternSplit[0])) return false;
        if(patternSplit.Count() > 2){
           for (var i = 1; i < patternSplit.Count() - 1; i++)
           {
               if (!line.Contains(patternSplit[i])) return false;
           }
        }
        if (!line.EndsWith(patternSplit[patternSplit.Count() - 1])) return false;
        return true;
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var matchingData = "quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog";
            var failingData = "I am batman";
            var pattern = "qu,pe,ov,og";
            if(IsMatch(pattern, matchingData))Console.WriteLine("{0} matches pattern {1}", pattern, matchingData);
            if(!IsMatch(pattern, failingData)) Console.WriteLine("{0} does not match {1}", pattern, failingData);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with the detailed code reference! It is almost perfect, except I have I concern: when there are more than one ',' in the pattern, you suggest to test if the line contains the splits, therefore if the user input matches any splits, IsMatch will return true. for example for arraylist{random, raedom, randem} user input 'r_n_o_', the program will match all three words.  Correct if I misunderstand the string.Contains.             Thank you so much again for your time!

Comment: that's correct @Kay that's what I tried to do. It should match `,` at the start, it should match `,` at the end and if there are more than two `,` then it should match inbetween the string.

Comment: Sorry to borther you again. @Aniket .In this case, for a longer word like academic, if you put in the pattern "a,a,e,m,c", the method you suggested will match the first a, last e, and any of three splits in the middle (a,e,m), so for example "acddmic, acaddic, acadenic" will all match the patter but they are not suppose to. I am trying to find the exact match for the pattern which I guess Contains is not good enough. If you have any idea to fix that problem, that will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Kay then it should be clearly defined as to how many characters `,` can match. Else, it will match everything in between (as per my code)